# Flutter SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile"

Tags: flutter

Have faced this issue multiple times now trying to build APK/App bundle with Flutter, can anyone tell what the issue is? It's saying my key.properties file is missing the store file, however it's definitely there and is 100% the correct path

My build gradle:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

  signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

My key.properties file(this is at the android folder of the flutter project):

```
storePassword=******
keyPassword=******
keyAlias=*****
storeFile=/Users/user/keystore/my_app/*****.jks
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Put your `key.properties` file inside the android folder of your project.

[Project]/android/key.properties

[image]

2. Edit your storeFile path on the `key.properties` with the jks file name only.

[image]

3. Add the jks file inside the android/app folder of your project.

[image]

**NOTE:** If this project is on a public repo add on android/.gitignore the jks and key.properties for security reasons.

Comment: Tried this previously, unfortunately still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the issue, perhaps this will help someone else in niche cases - basically the key.properties file was actually saved as key.properties.txt but MAC was masking this - I removed the .txt ext and all works now

Answer (score 0):

Is this the exact storefile path you added?

`storeFile=/Users/user/keystore/my_app/*****.jks`

If yes, then your location is probably incomplete.

It should look like this

`storeFile=C:/Users/user/keystore/my_app/*****.jks`

This is how it should start

`C:/Users` or `D:/Users`

---

Edited based on inputs from comment

Your `key.properties` file is at the root of Flutter project.

It actually has to be inside the `/android` folder.

Try moving it to android folder such that its location is like this

`[project]/android/key.properties`

Comment: I'm on mac so the path starts with a / (this is copied directly from the folder itself)

Comment: Edited. Can you give a try?

Comment: It's in the android folder but still no difference unfortunately

Comment: Changed the storefile address after moving to android folder? /Users/user/keystore/my_app/*****.jks

Comment: Also run flutter_clean

Comment: The storeFile address can stay the same as it's just a reference to where you're keeping the file on your machine - im thinking possible the path itself might be the issue, but its the path MAC gives me when asking for it, so not sure how it can be wrong

Comment: the storeFile is never in the flutter project as following the official release guide it says you only put the key.properties file in the android folder of the project, and the storeFile is kept somewhere else on your machine